# How to ignore a JPA ManyToOne property with null value on merge after JAXB deserialization?

Tags: jpa, merge, null, jaxb

Example use case:

```
class Address {

@XMLTransient
@ManyToOne(cascade={})
private Person person;

}
```

In my use case Address is serialized to XML via JAXB, modified in another system, deserialized from XML to a detached JPA entity and then merged back to db (em.merge(address)). As the Person property is marked @XMLTransient it is restored from XML with null.

As all Address' have a database entry and could be identified by there Id I'd like merge to ignore the Person property and just keep the database value for the relation (this has nothing to do with cascade).

Is there a way to tell JPA to ignore the Person property on merge or would I have to use an @XMLAdapter to set the property with the corresponding Person object before merge (btw I also use optimistic locking with @Version on all entities).

Any hints?

Miguel

Comment: Is an XMLAdapter really the only way?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't want this relation to be updated by JPA at all, upon a merge.  Is that correct?  If so, have you tried setting `updatable=false` on the `@ManyToOne`?